# How is this navigation control created

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ios7

The second image on this page from Apple's user interface design guide show a segmented control inside of a tall navigation bar:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Anatomy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH24-SW1

How has this been done? It seems to me that a UINavigationBar is always 64 pixels high, so I don't understand how they made this taller.

Is it a custom element (which would be surprising in this document), or is there an easy way to achieve this? I'm wondering if it's a UIToolbar... are they merged with the UINavigationBar under iOS 7? If so, how do we do this?

Note that I need to do this in a iPad app, where the UINavigationController is inside a split view controller.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the solution to this.

I had to override UINavigation bar with my custom subclass in order to change the height. By using the appearance proxy the title and navigation items can be repositioned correctly. Unfortunately the proxy can't be used to shift the back button's arrow up (on iOS 7), so we have to override layoutSubview to handle that.

```
#define kAppNavBarHeight 66.0

@implementation TATallNavigationBar

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self setupAppearance];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setupAppearance];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setupAppearance {

    static BOOL appearanceInitialised = NO;

    if (!appearanceInitialised) {

        // Update the appearance of this bar to shift the icons back up to their normal position

        CGFloat offset = 44 - kAppNavBarHeight;

        [[TATallNavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:offset forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[RRSNavigationBar class], nil] setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:offset forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[RRSNavigationBar class], nil] setBackButtonBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:offset forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[RRSNavigationBar class], nil] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, offset) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

        appearanceInitialised = YES;
    }
}

- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {

    return CGSizeMake(self.superview.frame.size.width, kNavBarheight);

}

- (void)layoutSubviews {

    static CGFloat yPosForArrow = -1;

    [super layoutSubviews];

    // There's no official way to reposition the back button's arrow under iOS 7. It doesn't shift with the title.
    // We have to reposition it here instead.

    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {

        // The arrow is a class of type _UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView. We're not calling any private methods, so I think
        // this is fine for the AppStore...

        if ([NSStringFromClass([view class]) isEqualToString:@"_UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView"]) {
            CGRect frame = view.frame;

            if (yPosForArrow < 0) {

                // On the first layout we work out what the actual position should be by applying our offset to the default position.

                yPosForArrow = frame.origin.y + (44 - kAppNavBarHeight);
            }

            // Update the frame.

            frame.origin.y = yPosForArrow;
            view.frame = frame;
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Note that it's easy to specify your subclass in XCode: clicking on the UINavigationController gives you access to the UINavigationBar in the left hand column. Click that and change it's subclass in the inspector.

I've also created a Gist for this:

https://gist.github.com/timothyarmes/7080170

Comment: How certain are you about the _UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView use being acceptable? It's an undocumented property, and your app could be susceptible to breaking if Apple change it.

Comment: I'm just testing the type of the class, so that should be fine from an acceptance point of view. It could potentially change in a future OS update, but I don't imagine that that will happen quickly so I'm OK with that personally. You could always try to find another way to check for that particular view (it the first version of my code I looked at its size and location, for example) if you prefer.

Comment: Another issue I have run into using my own version of this solution, is problems later on as I push more view controllers, which I do not need to be as tall - any thoughts on how to turn this into a more elegant solution?

Comment: What is `RRSNavigationBar`?

Comment: Oops, that was meant to be TATallNavigationBar. I've fixed that.